# How can I get the year from a Date object without using deprecated methods?

Tags: java, date, calendar, deprecated

I've been given an assignment where I need to create a set of interfaces and classes for a car rental company. I'm busy working on implementing a LicenceNumber class which must match the following spec:

> The licence number has three components. The first component is the concatenation of the initial of the first name of the driver with the initial of the last name of the driver. The second component is the year of issue of the licence. The third component is an arbitrary serial number. For example, the string representation of the licence number for a licence issued to Mark Smith in 1990 would have the form, MS-1990-10, where the 10 is a serial number that, with the initials and year, guarantees the uniqueness of the licence number as a whole.
>
> **You should use the java.util.Date class to represent dates. However, you must not use deprecated methods of the Date class. So, for example, in your test classes use java.util.Calendar to construct dates of birth and dates of issue of licences.** You can assume default time zone and locale. (Note, there are now better classes available in the java.time package which was introduced in Java 1.8 but it will be good experience to work with classes
> which are written less well).

So far I've got the following implementation for the LicenceNumber class:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class LicenceNumber {

private String licenceNo;

public LicenceNumber(Name driverName, Date issueDate){
    setLicenceNo(driverName, issueDate);
}

public String getLicenceNo() {
    return licenceNo;
}

public void setLicenceNo(Name driverName, Date issueDate) {
    String initials;
    initials = driverName.getForename().substring(0, 1) + driverName.getSurname().substring(0,1);
    System.out.println(initials);
    int issueYear = issueDate.getYear(); //Deprecated
}
}
```

I want to be able to get only the year from issueDate, but the only way I can figure out how to do it, is by using the deprecated method, getYear(). This is obviously against the criteria, so can anyone shed some light on how to get the Year from a Date object without using deprecated methods?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Have you tried using java.util.Calendar as specified in the assignment?

Comment: To my understanding, we're only allowed to use the Calendar utility in testing classes. For example I've constructed a Calendar using getInstance() then set it using (YYYY,MM,DD), and passed it into the DrivingLicense using getTime(). getTime() supposedly creates a date object.

Comment: Are you allowed to use any of the formatting classes, such as `SimpleDateFormat'?

Comment: I wouldn't imagine so. The fact that it states, **You should use the java.util.Date class to represent dates**, makes me think that's the only option we have.

Comment: You have passed a `Date` object to, e.g., `setLicenseNo()`. If you are not able to pass a `Calendar` object, then you will need to format the value out of the `Date` object in some fashion, since almost all of the `Date` methods are deprecated. If you cannot use `SimpleDateFormat`, then instantiate a Calendar object from the passed Date object, and obtain the year, but to me that is no different than formatting via a `DateFormat` object -- you are using some other object to obtain a detail from a `Date` object.

Comment: I kinda see where you're coming from, as no matter what it looks like I'm going to have to do some text manipulation to get the year. So looking at Lew Bloch's answer below, if I try DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(issueDate), then this yields 19-Mar-2015. I could then use substring to get the year but is there a faster way to get it?

Comment: @AndrewCoates, for the SimpleDateFormat, you can specify directly to only use a "year" as the format. I have posted an answer showing such an approach, along with two other potential ways to get just the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three ways to obtain the year from a `Date` object but avoiding the deprecated methods. Two of the approaches use other Objects (`Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`), and the third parses the `.toString()` of the `Date` object (and that method is *not* deprecated). The `.toString()` is potentially locale specific, and there could be issues with the approach in other locales, but I am going to assume (famous last words) that the year is always the only sequence of 4 digits. One could also understand the specific locale and use other parsing approaches. For example, standard US/English puts the year at the end (e.g., "Tue Mar 04 19:20:17 MST 2014"), one could use the `.lastIndexOf(" ")` on the `.toString()`.

```
/**
 * Obtains the year by converting the date .toString() and
 * finding the year by a regular expression; works by assuming that
 * no matter what the locale, only the year will have 4 digits
 */
public static String getYearByRegEx(Date dte) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    String year = "";

    if (dte == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null date!");
    }

    // match only a 4 digit year
    Pattern yearPat = Pattern.compile("^.*([\\d]{4}).*$");

    // convert the date to its String representation; could pass
    // this directly, but I prefer the intermediary variable for
    // potential debugging
    String localDate = dte.toString();

    // obtain a matcher, and then see if we have the expected value
    Matcher match = yearPat.matcher(localDate);
    if (match.matches() && match.groupCount() == 1) {
        year = match.group(1);
    }

    return year;
}


/**
 * Constructs a Calendar object, and then obtains the year
 * by using the Calendar.get(...) method for the year.
 */
public static String getYearFromCalendar(Date dte) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    String year = "";

    if (dte == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null date!");
    }

    // get a Calendar
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    // set the Calendar to the specific date; the reason why
    // Calendar is deprecated is this mutability
    cal.setTime(dte);

    // get the year using the .get method, and convert to a String
    year = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    return year;
}


/**
 * Uses the SimpleDateFormat with a format for only a year.
 */
public static String getYearByFormatting(Date dte)
        throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    String year = "";

    if (dte == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null date!");
    }

    // set a format only for the year
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");

    // format the date; the result is the year
    year = sdf.format(dte);

    return year;        
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2014, 
            Calendar.MARCH,
            04);

    Date dte = cal.getTime();

    System.out.println("byRegex: "+ getYearByRegEx(dte));
    System.out.println("from Calendar: "+ getYearFromCalendar(dte));
    System.out.println("from format: " + getYearByFormatting(dte));
}
```

All three approaches return the expected output based upon the test input.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! getYearFromCalendar() seems like it's the most appropriate method to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

<s>Try this</s>

<s>Date date = new Date();</s>
    <s>LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();</s>
    <s>int year  = localDate.getYear();</s>

Here is fix

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Substitute the new date with the date you are wanting to get the year from.

Comment: OP is not supposed to use the newer classes from Java 8.

Comment: I must have looked over that, been multitasking

Comment: Wait, so in a separate test class I have the following: Calendar d = Calendar.getInstance(); d.set(2015, 02, 19); LicenceNumber l = new LicenceNumber(andrew, d.getTime()); Meaning I've already passed the date object into the LicenceNumber.

Comment: you could do something like calendar.setTime(license.getIssuanceDate());  Is this the answer you are looking for?

Comment: Then to get the year from the issuance date just execute the next line calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm allowed to use Calendar inside anything other than the test classes though. Is there any chance you can use TeamViewer, so I can show you the rest of the implementation just to make explaining a little easier?

Comment: Date.getYear() was deprecated and replaced with Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);.. Without access to the Calendar object, I'm not sure how you would get the year.  You can email your code/instructions if you like.  josh@joshfischer.io

Comment: I've sent you the details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111475/discussion-between-andrew-coates-and-josh-fischer).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html and related classes. That can yield a string with just the "year" field from a given 'Date'.