# What Date Class is used in grails?

Tags: grails

I want to get the 4-digit year from today.

I have a variable `def todayDate = new Date()` in my controller.

I googled to see how to do it.  It pointed me to this page.

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html

There is a method called `toYear()`

Actually, none of the methods in this document works. The Date class in this document is not the same Date class in  the controller for sure.

Did Google show me the wrong document?  What is the correct way to get the 4-digit year from a Date()?

Comment: what version of grails are you using? the toYear method has been available since groovy 2.5 so you'll have to be using grails 4+ I believe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the year from a Date object without using deprecated methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37124269/how-can-i-get-the-year-from-a-date-object-without-using-deprecated-methods)

Comment: @tom6502 You should update your question with some clarity.  "What Date Class is used in grails?" - The answer to that is `java.util.Date`.  The rest of the question is addressing a separate issue.  "What is the correct way to get the 4-digit year from a Date()?" - If you mean from a `java.util.Date`. you could invoke `.format('yyyy')` on the `Date` to get the 4 digit year.  If what you really want is a 4 digit representation of today and you don't necessarily want it to come from a `Date`, then you should remove links to the `Date` docs and mention of `new Date()`.

Comment: There are features in Grails that require you to use a `Date`.  I know there is a claim below that there are no good reasons to use a `Date` and that may be correct, but if you want to use those features, you will need a `Date`.

Comment: `.format('yyyy')` does not work.  No such method error.  Majority of the answers here are outdated.  That's why I have to ask the same question again to looking for updated answer.

Comment: @Mike I am using Grails 4+  I am very confused how to or what to use to process Date in Grails.  The Grails document says when I create a Date, it is a java.util.Date class.  But majority of the Date methods I googled don't work with no such method errors.

Comment: @Basil I am not sure if the answers in the link is the answer I want to hear.  Basically, the answer is to convert java.util.Date to java.util.Calendar and use the method in the Calendar to get the year.  Is this the correct way or the standard way to process Date in Grails?

Comment: ".format('yyyy') does not work. No such method error." - I believe it does work.  Depending on what version of Groovy you are using you may need to add the groovy-dateutil library. I think we moved the date support stuff there in 2.5.  See .format('yyyy') does not work. No such method error.

Comment: The extension method is defined at https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/apache/groovy/dateutil/extensions/DateUtilExtensions.html#format(java.util.Date,java.lang.String).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/b8ce5da30d5e2ac01c9bd7f40d578910

Comment: "But majority of the Date methods I googled don't work with no such method errors." - Does your project express a dependency on groovy-dateutil?

Comment: See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/tom6502year. The code at https://github.com/jeffbrown/tom6502year/blob/f6f4ce1b8b57ad4bb3a8ae17baca3590443e1855/grails-app/controllers/tom6502year/DemoController.groovy#L6-L7 works because of the dependency at https://github.com/jeffbrown/tom6502year/blob/f6f4ce1b8b57ad4bb3a8ae17baca3590443e1855/build.gradle#L76.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

You said:

> I want to get the 4-digit year from today.

```
String.valueOf( LocalDate.now().getYear() )  // Java syntax.
```

> 2022

## Avoid legacy classes

The `java.util.Date` class is terribly flawed. Along with `Calendar` and the other legacy date-time classes, these were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on these legacy classes. I suggest you do the same.

## `Year`

(Forgive the Java syntax as I do not know Groovy.)

If all you want is the year, use [`Year`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/time/Year.html) class.

```
Year currentYear = Year.now( z ) ;
int y = currentYear.getValue() ;
```

## `LocalDate#getYear`

For a date-only value, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/time/LocalDate.html).

### Time zone

Determining the current date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.

(Again, Java syntax.)

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;  // Or, ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
int year = today.getYear() ;
```

---

I do not see all these methods in your Groovy API documentation. Perhaps I do not know how that doc works. The classes listed here are built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: "For a date-only value, use LocalDate." - I think the question is how to get a 4 digit year out of a `Date`.  Using `LocalDate` doesn't address that question.  There are a lot of good reasons to use a `Date`, including interacting with APIs that return or accept those.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown ??? How does `LocalDate.now().getYear()` not address the Question’s goal of getting the year as a four-digit integer?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown There are no good reasons to use `Date`. If interoperating with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, write your code using *java.time*, then call the new `to`/`from` conversion methods added to the old classes.

Comment: "How does LocalDate.now().getYear() not address the Question’s goal of getting the year as a four-digit integer?" - I think that demonstrates how to get a year from a `LocalDate`.  I may have misunderstood the question.  I thought the question wanted to know how to get a 4 digit year from a `Date`.

Comment: "There are no good reasons to use Date. " - Great feedback.  Thank you!

Comment: "There are no good reasons to use Date. " Do you think we should remove the custom `java.util.Date` support from Groovy?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Your first sentence literally asks “get the 4-digit year from today”.  That is what I showed. Discussing `Date` is pointless as (a) `Date` is obsolete, and (b) the context of the question does not require `Date`. Replace `def todayDate = new Date()` with `def todayDate = LocalDate.now()`. When you need the year call the `getYear` method on `LocalDate`.

Comment: "Your first sentence literally asks “get the 4-digit year from today”." -  That isn't my sentence.  That is from the question.  I think I misunderstood "What is the correct way to get the 4-digit year from a Date()?" and assumed the question is about the `Date` class.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Very well, in that case your Question is[ a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37124269/642706).

Comment: I have deleted my answer that explains how to do it with a `Date.  I think I misunderstood.

Comment: "Very well, in that case your Question is a duplicate." - Ok.  Roger that.  Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Whoops, I confused you for the author of the Question. And I mistakenly started a “chat”; now deleted.

Comment: @Basil I am still confused.  You show me a link that tells me to use the Calendar class but your answer says not to use the Date or the Calendar class.  Is using LocalDate the correct or standard way to process date in Grails?

Comment: I understand that there is no standard for date (time).  That's why when I google how to process date, I get tons of different suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading and trying to understand all the comments and checking the links.  I think I get what is going on here.

When I declare a Date variable in Grails, it is a java.util.Date.  If I google how to work with the Date, this gets confusing.  The methods that process the Date are not from the java.util.Date class.  Majority of the java.util.Date methods are deprecated.  The methods you can find from google are actually coming from the `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil:3.0.9` Groovy date enhancement package.

So, the Date is a java.util.Date but the methods are from the enhancement package.